# Keep getting '[object Object]' when trying to access asp variable in jquery using <%= %>

Tags: jquery, asp.net, user-controls

Hi I have a user control and I want to access a variable in the .cs file from the .ascx file using jquery. This is how I do it:

```
var stat = $('<%=status%>');
```

when I try to do `alert(stat);`, I get an alert box containing this: `[object Object]`

In my .cs file, `public string status = "some text";`

Any help, please? Thanks

Comment: If that's a textbox you should add `.val()` to get the value, because you are getting the textbox, that's an object

Comment: @JorgeF No, it's not a textbox. It's just a string variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a `jQuery` selector there, because status is not a control on your page rather its a variable on server, simply do this:-

```
var stat = '<%=status%>';
alert(stat);
```